# In reimplemented paint function of QItemDelegate, setFont is not working

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qitemdelegate

I have reimplemented `paint()` function for `QTreeWidget`, I want to show data of second column bold, but it doesn't work.

How can i fix it?

```
void extendedQItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                                  const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                  const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    const QString txt = index.data().toString();
    painter->save();
    QFont painterFont;
    if (index.column() == 1) {
        painterFont.setBold(true);
        painterFont.setStretch(20);
    }
    painter->setFont(painterFont);
    drawDisplay(painter, option, rect, txt);
    painter->restore();
}
```

I attached a screen shot of the problem, second half should be bold

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please always explain in general how it does not work. It is perhaps even better to provide screenshots if it is a visual issue.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add your `extendedQItemDelegate` to the `QTreeView`/`QTreeWidget` object via the [`setItemDelegate`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) member function.

As an example:

```
QTreeWidget* tree_view = ...;
extendedQItemDelegate* extended_item_delegate = ...;
tree_view->setItemDelegate(extended_item_delegate);
```

Comment: here is my code :extendedQItemDelegate *delg = new extendedQItemDelegate;
    treeEvents->setItemDelegate(delg);

Comment: i googled my probelm and i found that i should change const QStyleOptionViewItem &option font but because it is const i can't change it, i try to change a copy of it but it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of the `const QStyleOptionViewItem &option`, apply your font changes to that copy, then paint using your copy instead of the original `option` passed to the function.

```
void extendedQItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                                  const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                                  const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    const QString txt = index.data().toString();
    painter->save();
    QStyleOptionViewItem optCopy = option;     // make a copy to modify
    if (index.column() == 1) {
        optCopy.font.setBold(true);            // set attributes on the copy
        optCopy.font.setStretch(20);
    }
    drawDisplay(painter, optCopy, rect, txt);  // use copy to paint with
    painter->restore();
}
```

(Just realized this is an old question but it had popped up to the top of `qt` tags.)